# wpf rotate image around center

Tags: wpf, xaml, animation

I have an image on a button which I would like to rotate when the user clicks it. I allmost have it to work. The image rotates fine on click, but it doesn't rotate round its center.

How can I make the image rotate around its center and not the top left corner?

Here is my code:

```
<Button Name="btnRefreshPortList"
    Grid.Column="1"
    Margin="10 0 0 0"
    Command="{Binding RefreshPortList}">
                        
    <Image Source="Images/refresh.jpg" 
        Height="15">
        <Image.RenderTransform>
            <RotateTransform x:Name="AnimatedRotateTransform" Angle="0" />
        </Image.RenderTransform>
        <Image.Triggers>
            <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="MouseDown">
                <BeginStoryboard>
                    <Storyboard>
                        <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="AnimatedRotateTransform" 
                            Storyboard.TargetProperty="Angle" 
                            By="10"        
                            To="360" 
                            Duration="0:0:0.5" 
                            FillBehavior="Stop" />
                    </Storyboard>
                </BeginStoryboard>
            </EventTrigger>
        </Image.Triggers>
    </Image>
</Button>
```

Comment: Usually adding a translation before a rotation can sort this.

Answer (score 64, accepted):

Just set `RenderTransformOrigin` to (0.5, 0.5) on the image

```
<Image Source="Images/refresh.jpg" 
    RenderTransformOrigin=".5,.5"
    Height="15">
...
```

Comment: I get System.UnauthorizedAccessException if I set RenderTransformOrigin before the Rotation, otherwise, without setting it, the Rotation works fine.

Comment: @JohnGlen that's weird... UnauthorizedAccessException is a security-related error. I see no reason why it should be thrown in this case. Looks like a bug in WPF...

Comment: Yea, seemed really weird. I created a bug report.
I did manage to get it working using a transform though.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74447383/how-do-you-rotate-an-image-around-its-center-point-in-a-c-sharp-code-behind-file/74447401#74447401